# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Error while partitioning domain on scipy bvp solver

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to solve a fourth-order beam equation numerically using `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp`. To do this, I converted the fourth-order differential equation into a system of four first-order differential equations.

```py
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

def fun(x, y):
    if x < L-a:
        return np.vstack((y[1], y[2],y[3], k*y[0]))
    else:
        return np.vstack((y[1], y[2],y[3], np.zeros(len(x))))
        

def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0], ya[1], yb[0]-y_0, yb[2]])

x = np.linspace(0, L, 50)
y_guess = np.zeros((4, x.size))

res_a = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_guess)
```

Where `a`, `L`, `k`, and `y_0` are constants. When I run this, I get the error:

```py
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Now I did search online about this error, and I see why it appears. It's taking `x < L-a` as a boolean statement and the solutions online tell us to use `any()` or `all()` after the conditional. But I think what I want to do is different. I do not want to check if any or all elements of array `x` are greater than `L-a`, but I want to apply a forcing function in the differential equation only when `x` is in that range. What is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: where o where did this error occur?  FULL ERROR MESSAGE!

Comment: It's unclear when you want to apply the forcing. `x` is a vector. Do you only want to apply a forcing where the condition is met? Also, use `np.zeros_like(x)` rather than `np.zeros(len(x))`.

Comment: You also didn't provide values for `a`, `k`, or `L`, so we cannot run this code ourselves.

Comment: You also didn't give a value for `y_0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the last element of `fun` to be 0 where `x >= L-a` and equal to `k*y[0]` where `x < L-a`, you can create a `force` vector that you initialize to 0 and then set equal to `k*y[0]` at the indices where `x < L-a` is satisfied. To test the code I made up values for `a`, `L`, `k`, and `y_0`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

def fun(x, y):
    force = np.zeros_like(x)
    force[x < L-a] = k*y[0][x < L-a]
    
    return np.vstack((y[1], y[2],y[3], force))
        

def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0], ya[1], yb[0]-y_0, yb[2]])

L = 5
a = 1
k = 0.5
y_0 = 2

x = np.linspace(0, L, 50)
y_guess = np.zeros((4, x.size))

res = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_guess)
```

I also plotted the 4 vector results, corresponding to different orders of derivatives.

[image]